# Stop a program from reading argument

Tags: shell, arguments

I ran into an issue where I am using a wrapper around a compiler to do static code analysis.

The command looks like:

```
sourceanalyzer -b Program clang -E File
```

The -E argument is for the clang compiler; however, `sourceanalyzer` reads it then throws an error because it is not valid.

Is there any way to make `sourceanalyzer` ignore the `-E`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
sourceanalyzer -b Program clang -- -E File
```

Or

```
sourceanalyzer -b Program -- clang -E File
```

Depending on whether sourceanalyzer expects "clang" as a parameter or not.